# Converting any method to retry-able method in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a method that should take an arbitrary method or code block and it should convert the method or code-block to retry-able method.

Following example is intended to demonstrate what I need

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}

object Retry {
    retry[A, B](f: A => Try[B], r: Int): A => Try[B] = {
        // return a function g and when g is invoked with parameters
        // f should be tried (if failed) r number of time otherwise
        // result of first successful execution of f should be returned
        // from g. retry should work with any arbitrary function with
        // any number/type of parameters
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you signal that `f` has failed? Perhaps it should be `f: A => Try[B]`?

Comment: What have you tried doing? Did you try implementing the method? Wehre are you stuck?

Comment: There is usually more to retrying than just running the function again. For example, you might want to wait between tries. Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/Mortimerp9/5430595)

Comment: `f` as "any arbitrary function with any number/type of parameters" is not so easy. Functions with different signatures are different function types.

Comment: There's always https://monix.io/api/2.3/monix/eval/Coeval.html#onErrorRestart(maxRetries:Long):monix.eval.Coeval[A] if you pack the computation into a `Coeval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to abstract over arity, which is pretty advanced, you'll have to use [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), a library for generic programming.

Building on @chengpohi's answer:

```
import shapeless._, ops.function._
import scala.util.Try

def retry[F, L <: HList, R](f: F, r: Int = 1)(implicit fnToP: FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => R], fnFromP: FnFromProduct.Aux[L => R, F]): F = {
  val fn = fnToP(f)
  def repeat(a: L): R = {
    for (_ <- 0 to r) {
      val tried = Try(fn(a))
      if (tried.isSuccess) {
        return tried.get
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException(s"retry $r failed")
  }
  fnFromP(repeat _)
}
```

It works:

```
scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> val f = retry( (a: Int) => if (i < 10) {i += 1; println(s"try $i"); throw new RuntimeException} else a * 3, 42)
f: Int => Int = shapeless.ops.FnFromProductInstances$$anon$2$$Lambda$1489/1404497488@1d49a23c

scala> f(5)
try 1
try 2
try 3
try 4
try 5
try 6
try 7
try 8
try 9
try 10
res4: Int = 15

scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> val f = retry( (a: String, b: Int) => if (i < 10) {i += 1; println(s"try $i"); throw new RuntimeException} else a * b, 42)
f: (String, Int) => String = shapeless.ops.FnFromProductInstances$$anon$3$$Lambda$1492/121867201@1a22b89c

scala> f("foo", 5)
try 1
try 2
try 3
try 4
try 5
try 6
try 7
try 8
try 9
try 10
res5: String = foofoofoofoofoo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def retry[A, B](f: A => B, r: Int = 1): A => B = {
    def repeat(a: A): B = {
      for (_ <- 0 to r) {
        val tried = Try(f(a))
        if (tried.isSuccess) {
          return tried.get
        }
      }
      throw new RuntimeException(s"retry $r failed")
    }
    repeat
  }
```

There is a simple way to do this, `try` if **Success** and **return**, otherwise `throw Exception`

Comment: Above will work with function that take only one parameter, but if function accept two or more or no parameters than such implementation is failing

Comment: @ShamshadAlam Then call it like `Function.untupled(retry(arbitraryFunction.tupled, 42))`.

Comment: @ShamshadAlam, unfortunately for now you can't express entity "Function of arbitrary arity" in the Scala type system so you can't have single `retry` function. The trick by Jasper-M might reduce code duplication but not the need to declare many `retry` functions (actually up to 22 for now).