# How to write a retry function?

Tags: scala, error-handling

Suppose I've got a function `foo:Int => Try[Int]` and I need to call it with retries. That is, I need to call it till it returns `Success` at most `k` times.

I am writing a function `retry` like that:

```
def retry(k: retries)(fun: Int => Try[Int]): Try[Int] = ???
```

I want `retry` to return either `Success` or *the last* `Failure`. How would you write it ?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074016/converting-any-method-to-retry-able-method-in-scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the one I use, which is generic over any thunk returning `T`:

```
@tailrec
final def withRetry[T](retries: Int)(fn: => T): Try[T] = {
  Try(fn) match {
    case x: Success[T] => x
    case _ if retries > 1 => withRetry(retries - 1)(fn)
    case f => f
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it be done without recursion ? Just curious.

Comment: @Michael I guess every tailrec recursion can be written via loop.

Comment: @Michael You definitely can, but it's a bit less elegant IMO

Comment: @SergeyLagutin Yes. I meant writing w/o recursion _functionally_ (i.e. w/o mutable state).

Comment: @Michael Without mutable state is going to be harder. But the mutable state is all scoped at the method level and isn't visible outside, so it won't be that bad.

Comment: Maybe you are right ... On the other hand, what if I need another function `WithRetry2` to return _all_ failures rather than only the last one ? I would like to reuse `WithRetry` to write `WithRetry2` instead of writing it from scratch.

Comment: @Michael You can write a recursive method which accumulates all errors and returns them, and have a specific `withRetrySingle` which returns the tail of the accumulator (or the head, depending on your insertion order).

Comment: Thanks. I want to try using a lazy collection.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov what does the `case f => f` handle? My understanding is `Try[T]` returns either `Success[T]` or `Failure[T]`.

Comment: @billydh It handles the exaution of the retry, and returning whatever was yielded by `f`, which is going to be a failure. Would be similar if we matched on `case f: Failure[_] => ..`