# Retry function without recursion

Tags: scala, error-handling, lazy-sequences

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440412/how-to-write-a-retry-function).

I would like to write a non-recursive `retry` function using the signature from the [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48440465/521070). Note that this implementation uses `view` as a lazy sequence.

```
def withRetries[T](retries: Short)(fun: => T): Try[T] = {
    (0 until retries).view.map(_ => Try(fun)).partition(_.isFailure) match {
        case (a, b) if b.isEmpty => a.last
        case (_, b) => b.head
    }
}
```

Does it make sense ?
How would you improve it ?

Comment: What's the point of making it non-recursive? Is it just a brain teaser, like swapping two ints without using a temporary variable? This is not a good implenentation, because it will run `fun` N times, even if every one of them succeeds.

Comment: Also you may have to use mutable variable to keep track of past result and stuff.

Comment: @pamu I don't want to use mutable state.

Comment: Michael, but what's exactly wrong with recursion especially given Scala has @tailrec annotation?

Comment: @Dima Thanks. You are right. The implementation is not good. It does not run `fun` N times if every run succeeds but it runs it _twice_. Need to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, twice indeed. I still don't get it what is the point of his exercise.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you are asking ... but for the life of me I can't begin to imagine why you would want that ...

```
 def withRetries[T](retries: Int)(fun: => T) = (1 to retries)
   .foldLeft[Try[T]](Failure(new Exception)) {
     case (x@Success(_), _) => x
     case _ => Try(fun)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `view`-based solution is poor since it executes `fun` twice even the first run succeeds. My new solution is:

```
def withRetries[T](retries: Short)(fun: => T): Try[T] = {
    val stream = (0 until retries).toStream.map(_ => Try(fun))
    stream.find(_.isSuccess) getOrElse stream.last
}
```

The code looks nice but I believe its performance is poor because of `Stream`.
On the other hand if the number of retries is small and `fun` is time consuming the `Stream` performance does not matter that much.